# How to add a new key to multiple indices of an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I've got an array of three people. I want to add a new key to multiple objects at once based on an array of indices. Clearly my attempt at using multiple indices doesn't work but I can't seem to find the correct approach.

```
var array = [
  {
    "name": "Tom",
  },
  {
    "name": "Dick",
  },
  {
    "name": "Harry",
  }
];

array[0,1].title = "Manager";
array[2].title = "Staff";
console.log(array);
```

Which returns this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Tom",
  },
  {
    "name": "Dick",
    "title": "Manager"
  },
  {
    "name": "Harry",
    "title": "Staff"
  }
]
```

But I'd like it to return this.

```
[
  {
    "name": "Tom",
    "title": "Manager"
  },
  {
    "name": "Dick",
    "title": "Manager"
  },
  {
    "name": "Harry",
    "title": "Staff"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

1st method::

```
array[0].title = "Manager";
array[1].title = "Manager";
array[2].title = "Staff";
```

array[0,1] will not work.

2nd method::

```
for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++) { 
   var msg = "Manager"; 
   if(i===2) { 
      msg = "Staff" 
   } 
   array[i].title = msg 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use multiple keys by using any separator in arrays.

Wrong: `array[x, y]`
Correct: `array[x]` and `array[y]`

In your case, it will be `array[0].title = array[1].title = "manager"`;

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `

```
for (var i=0; var<= array.length; i++){

array[i].title = "manager";

}`
```

Or you can change it around so var is less than or equal to any n range of keys in the index.

EDIT: instead make var <= 1. The point is to make for loops for the range of indices you want to change the title to.

Comment: You have a lot of syntax errors out there. Your condition block in `for` loop is incorrect. You are iterating the loop one extra time. And lastly, you are setting `title` properties of all objects in the array `array` to `"manager"`.

Comment: clarified what I meant with the iterations. And how it my condition block incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a helper function like this

```
function setMultiple(array, key, indexes, value) 
{
    for(i in array.length)
    {
        if(indexes.indexOf(i)>=0){
            array[i][key] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

And then

```
setMultiple(array, "title", [0,1], "Manager");
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a bigger set of array objects.

```
var array = [
  {
    "name": "Tom",
  },
  {
    "name": "Dick",
  },
  {
    "name": "Harry",
  },
  .
  .
  .
];
```

Create an object for the new keys you want to add like so:

```
let newKeys = {
  'Manager': [0,2],
  'Staff': [1]
}
```

Now you can add more such titles here with the required indexes.

with that, you can do something like:

```
function addCustomProperty(array, newKeys, newProp) {
  for (let key in newKeys) {       
    array.forEach((el, index) => {  
      if (key.indexOf(index) > -1) { // if the array corresponding to
        el[newProp] = key            // the key has the current array object 
      }                              // index, then add the key to the 
    })                               // object.
  }
  return array
}

let someVar = addCustomProperty(array, newKeys, 'title')
```